# Prisma where clause in delete and update API

Tags: prisma

I'm newbie of prisma, and previously I use TypeORM.
I try to use where clause in delete api.
I think it is problem of the unique index...

> this is my schema

```
model author {
  id          String        @id()
  first_name  String
  second_name String  
  description String?

  @@unique([first_name, second_name])
}
```

> this is what i want to use in query

```
prisma.datasets.delete({
  where: {
    id: datasetId,
    first_name: 'kim'
  }
```

> But in real, i must put into second_name in where clause

```
prisma.datasets.delete({
  where: {
    id: datasetId,
    first_name_second_name: {
      first_name: 'kim',
      second_name: 'sonny'
    }
  }
})
```

I want to partially use where clause in update, delete api!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The point of using `@@unique` on a model is that it creates a unique constraint on your database that says "This combination of fields will always be unique". This is how you can use `findUnique` on your database to find an `author` with only the `first_name` and `second_name` fields.

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unique-1

If you want to delete ONE dataset given `datasetId`, you would only need to pass `datasetId` IF that field is unique.

```js
prisma.datasets.delete({
  where: {
    id: datasetId,
  }
})
```

If `datasetId` is not unique then you MUST pass `first_name_second_name` in which case you MUST pass both `first_name` and `second_name`, because that's the only way Prisma can find the item you are trying to delete.

You can also do `prisma.dataset.deleteMany` if you want to delete MANY datasets if `datasetId` is not unique AND you only have `first_name`.